# Wifi is not working properly in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I have Lenovo B480 laptop on which i am using multiple OS namely windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. When i first open Ubuntu and try to connect to wifi network it get connected but internet is not working, but on the other hand if i first open window and than try to connect to wifi internet it get connected and internet works fine and after that if i restart the system and open the ubuntu than try to connect it get connects as well as internet also works fine. I don't know why it happens? Please tell me what should i do so that when ever i open ubuntu, the internet works fine?

I got frusted that whenever i want to work on ubuntu every time i have to first open the windows than i have to restart the system to use ubuntu to access the internet.

After running the command   "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" the output is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0608]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 :  I have edited the answer and also add the following output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Broadcom wl driver. Run

```
 sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

if you have internet connection.

Comment: Thanx. Now it is working fine. :)